# Changing Default Title on WooCommerce Single Products Pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I suppose this is something simple, but couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Currently, my website shows `<h1>"Products"</h1>` title on shop archive page, but on single product pages  as well. Is it possible to change default title on single product pages to product name?

[Here is my website](http://ta65doctor.com/newwordpress/product/ta-65-skin/). As you can see, above breadcrumbs, there is a default shop title. And there I want to display, product name instead.

```
<section class="<?php echo esc_attr($class_name) ?>" <?php echo wp_kses_post($bg_style); ?>>
    <div class="page-title-inner">
        <div class="container"><h1><?php echo esc_html($page_title); ?></h1> <?php great_store_the_breadcrumb(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You need to find, in your theme, where the breadcrumbs are located (via Sublime or Notepad++), search `.page-title-inner` and see what's the code given there. After that you can provide that code here and people can help you, because we don't have much to do than guess...

Comment: Breadcrubms have nothing with that. Here is my code:


`<section class="<?php echo esc_attr($class_name) ?>" <?php echo wp_kses_post($bg_style); ?>>
 <div class="page-title-inner">
  <div class="container">
   <h1><?php echo esc_html($page_title); ?></h1>
   <?php great_store_the_breadcrumb(); ?>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>`

Comment: Ok, you have variable `$page_title`. Can you locate what it is, and add the code for that as well? You could add a [conditional](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/) to check if you're on product page, and get the product name and assign it to that variable.

Comment: I found it in my archive-product-top.php

`<?php if (apply_filters('woocommerce_show_page_title', true)) : ?>

 <section class="<?php echo esc_attr($class_name) ?>"  <?php echo wp_kses_post($bg_style); ?>>
  <div class="page-title-inner">
   <div class="container">
    <h1><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php great_store_the_breadcrumb(); ?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>`

Comment: Ok, this should get you the page title, instead of `<?php if (apply_filters('woocommerce_show_page_title', true)) : ?>` you can add `<?php if ( is_product() ) : ?>`. And if you still get the same thing, you can use `get_the_title()` instead of `woocommerce_page_title()`.